# Picasso library error unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

```
   if(!image!!.equals("default")){
        Picasso.with( applicationContext )
           .load("image")
           .placeholder(R.drawable.profile_img)
           .into(settingsProfileId)
   }
```

with is getting error `unresolved reference` 
How to solve this error

Comment: Which version of Picasso are you using

Comment: I've got the same with `get()`. Android Studio shows `Unresolved reference: get`

Answer (score 12):

You are using old version u need update ur library...

[See more details.](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

In Gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Java:

```
Picasso.get() .load(url) .resize(50, 50) .centerCrop() .into(imageView)
```

Comment: In this version how to use applicationContext with get method? That's why i am using previous version

Comment: it's such a strange version compared to "2.5.2". Because of the weirdness I was stuck on it until I checked the github releases list for picasso

Answer (score 0):

So i got the answer 
the error is that the Picasso library version 7.3 is not supported to .with function 
so to solve it change to lower version
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'

Comment: Or just use the newly provided `Picasso.get()`